# Can elements in a group have more than one inverse

Tags: matrices, group-theory, trigonometry, elementary-set-theory

I had to prove if a set of $2\times 2$ matrices is a group with respect to multiplication where I define a group as the set of all
$$A_\alpha = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\alpha&-\sin\alpha \\ \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha \end{bmatrix}$$
where $\alpha\in\Bbb R$.

Now its fairly easy to prove that this set is non-empty and satisfies closure and associativity w.r.t multiplication as well as identity. What I was confused about here was that since $A_{2\pi+\alpha}=A_\alpha$, then will this set be considered to have more than one identity element as $A_{2n\pi}$ will be the identity element.

Likewise, when finding out the inverse, I had already derived that $A_\alpha*A_\beta=A_{\alpha+\beta}$, if I took inverse of $A_\alpha$ to be $A_\beta$, the relation between $\beta\;\text{and}\;\alpha\;\text{is}$ $$\beta=2n\pi-\alpha$$
Here, again, although we get the same matrices for all the different $\beta$ values, will we consider $\alpha$ to have more than one inverses. 
In short, what I am confused about is that we get a single matrix for a lot of different values of $\alpha$. So are they all supposed to be considered as the same element of the set of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No" as answer on the question in the title.

If $a=b$ then the set $\{a,b\}$ has exactly one element.

You could say that $a$ and $b$ are just labels of the same mathematical object.

In your case $\{A_{2n\pi+\alpha}\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}=\{A_{\alpha}\}$ since $A_{2n\pi+\alpha}=A_{\alpha}$ for each $n\in\mathbb Z$.

So there is exactly one identity.

Same story for inverses.

Answer (score 5):

The catch here is that $A_{\alpha+2\pi}$ *is actually equal* to $A_{\alpha}$ (since $\cos{(x+2\pi)}=\cos(x)$ and likewise for $\sin$). So the matrices $A_{-\alpha}$, $A_{2\pi-\alpha}$ are indeed both inverses for $A_{\alpha}$, but that is not a problem, since they are the same element!